# Independence from moments

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Assume that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed and absolutely continuous. Suppose that 
$E[X^aY^b]=E[X^a]E[Y^b]$ for all $a,b$ natural numbers.
Is it true that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The hypothesis implies $Ef(X)g(Y) =Ef(X)Eg(Y)$ for all polynomials $f$ and $g$, hence for all bounded continuous functions $f$ and $g$ and this implies independence.